# How can I fetch javascript forms and buttons with for/foreach?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to js. It could be something simple, sorry for asking. How can I create the 3 forms I have given below as static, with for or foreach?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    document.querySelector('.form1').appendChild(input);
  });
});

$(function() {
  $("#btn2").click(function() {
    document.querySelector('.form2').appendChild(input);
  });
});

$(function() {
  $("#btn3").click(function() {
    document.querySelector('.form3').appendChild(input);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
for(let i = 0 i < 3; i++) {
    $(function() {
      $(`#btn${i+1}`).click(function() {
        document.querySelector(`.form${i+1}`).appendChild(input);
      });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can bind button ids and forms class into an object

```
const formsButtons = [
   { buttonId: "#btn1", formClass: ".form1"},
   { buttonId: "#btn2", formClass: ".form2"},
   { buttonId: "#btn3", formClass: ".form3"},
]
```

and then loop through this object to bind the input

```js
formsButtons.forEach(({buttonId, formClass}) => {
   $(function() {
      $(buttonId).click(function() {
         document.querySelector(formClass).appendChild(input);
      });
   });
})
```

Comment: This answer has the most potential to escalate if the project goes wide.

Answer (score 1):

This is to all the forEach bias outhere :)

```js
let forms = ['form1','form2','form3']; 
forms.forEach(function (e) {
   $(`#btn_${e}`).click(function() {
    //example to run it on snipet, you should do your thing with the inputs i guess
    let input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'text';
    input.value = `Input for: ${e}`;  
    document.querySelector(`.${e}`).appendChild(input);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class='form1'></form>
<form class='form2'></form>
<form class='form3'></form>
<button id="btn_form1">Create form 1</button>
<button id="btn_form2">Create form 2</button>
<button id="btn_form3">Create form 3</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using jQuery,
use **$(function() {})** mean the script inside this function will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute, it is the shorthand of **$( document ).ready()**, read more at:
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

in this case, you should edit like below:

```
$(function () {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
   $(`#btn${i}`).click(function () {
    document.querySelector(`.form${i}`).appendChild(input);
   });
  }
});
```

or use javascript instead:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  function appendElement(id) {
    document.querySelector(`.form${id}`).appendChild(input);
  }
  for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  document.getElementById(`btn${i}`).addEventListener("click", appendElement(i), false);
   }
});
```